# Wordpress site migration addvice

Tags: plugins, themes, theme-options, migration

I have created my WordPress site with purchased theme from themeforest locally in Bitnami. I've made a couple of pages using visual composer plugin changed some settings in theme options and created a child theme.

Now I'm trying to migrate my site to different computer also running Bitnami WordPress. For this I tried using ***All-in-One WP Migration*** plugin but got stuck at 4% importing a couple of times. I also found out that many times the problem with migration is that theme options are not transfered and you have to redo them on the new site.

That being said I'm looking for other solutions. I saw that there are many plugins that allow migrating old site database without any problems. I also found out that there is this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/customizer-export-import/) supports transferring customizer settings. If you have any advice or I have said something totally wrong please correct me. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. You don't need to use plugins in order to migrate some wordpress from one place from another.

**1) Make backups.**

When you have a backup with, for example [Updraft](https://wordpress.org/plugins/updraftplus/) you can easily make backup with all things, and restore backup.

**2) Hard migration. Best migration.**

I am doing this type of migration most of the times. Simply take whole your FTP and migrate it to another computer. Do export from the whole wordpress database.

Problems encountered:

- when you migrate, you need to check .htaccess in order to make translation for you web page to correct folder. Mistake here will be simple. You will see homepage but everyother page will end up not found. Changing .htaccess solve this
- Database adresses. Most common problem here is that you need to know how will your domain look like after migration. You need to go to wp_options and change site_url and homepage url in order to work wordpress right. Second problem here is that you need to find every entry in database where is old url and change it to the new one.
- wp_posts table. When you migrate and old wordpress instalation with lots of posts, you will surely encounter problem with overflowing wp_posts table. You will need to add lines to database manually by a few lines at the time.

With this system i normally migrate huge webs from one server to another with no other problems.
Improvement here will be some sort of repository where you can storage whole website with database and just clone repository to different place. Very nice and work friendly is to make same users and passwords to the database on a different places.

Hope it helps.

Comment: are 1 and 2 steps or choices?

Comment: is there any link on how to do the option 2)?

Comment: Step 1 is an idea, 2 is done and working. I have no video about doing it sry.

Comment: when you say "take whole your FTP and migrate it" which files from Bitnami install do you mean? In my apps folder I have phpmyadmin and wordpress folders.

Comment: In that case it is whole wordpress folder. Sorry. Don't using Bitnami.

Comment: When I tried coping that folder I get an error for wordpress/bnconfig permission denied. Then I skip that file and from there on I can not open my site anymore it says "Error establishing a database connection"

Comment: If you have error in establishing dtb connection, try to change wp_config.php. Here are stored information about FTP and about dtb access. Maybe you can have different host, pass or user name to the DTB. That is why i wrote about creating database users with same credentials on both sides of migration. If Bitnami is same sort of localhost server. I have only good reference on Vertrigo for this usage. Everything else was not good in performence for me.